# "Polymorphism is not the same as method overloading or method overriding."

Tags: polymorphism, overloading, overriding

"Polymorphism is not the same as method overloading or method overriding. ... Neither ... are by themselves implementations of polymorphism".

This is a quote from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming)

However in the book "Object-Oriented Programming" Timothy Budd states there are "four different forms of polymorphism":

- overloading (ad hoc polymorphism)
- overriding (inclusion polymorphism)
- polymorphic variable (assignment polymorphism)
- generics

Who is right? Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "polymorphism". and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343625/why-does-wikipedia-say-polymorphism-is-not-the-same-as-method-overloading-or-met

Comment: Wait... a different source contradicted Wikipedia? *gasp*

Comment: Don't look to comments for real answers... you will surely be disappointed

Comment: It seems they define their terms differently, so as long as the context and definition of a conversation is known at the begining, either one of these *could* be correct. The problem is when Dev A takes the wikipedia defintion as more correct and Dev B takes Mr. Budd's definition as more correct, without communicating these decisions to each other.

Comment: @unquiet mind - thanks, I read the accepted answer in your link which states: "Polymorphism (very simply said) is a possibility to use a derived class where a base class is expected". Does this mean that in a dynamic language like Ruby, where there is no "expected" class, polymorphism does not apply?

Comment: @Question - The dynamic nature of languages like Ruby does not at all mean that certain classes are not 'expected' by your code. Just because the compiler does not enforce typing does not mean that your code doesn't expect a certain class to exist at a certain time. So your answer is "No - polymorphism most certainly does still apply, because dynamic code itself can still 'expect' a certain type at any certain place"

Comment: For example: If you test a variable to see if it is/derives from a certain 'base' class, to see if it has a certain member - say a function with a certain signature - and then you call that member if so, polymorphism could be in play there, because a derived class of the base class you would expect to have that member could be in use, and its method would be called rather than the base.

Answer (score 3):

Polymorphism is a characteristic or feature of programming languages. Programming languages either support it or they don’t. Since programming languages fall under the umbrella of sometimes substantially different paradigms, different paradigms (functional programming or object oriented programming) may have slightly different interpretations and applications of HOW polymorphism is expressed in that particular paradigm.

As far as I know, in OOP polymorphism is considered one of the basic principles and a very distinctive one. Most of the object oriented languages have polymorphism among its many features. In a nutshell, polymorphism is best seen when the caller of an object with polymorphic implementation is not aware of the exact type the object is. Is is often a consequence of inheritance and casting, is also called [subtype polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtype_polymorphism), and works through the use of  [vTables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table).

I share the idea (along with many authors) that operator overload is a manifestation of polymorphism. So if you overload the == operator to take TypeA == TypeB, you are effectively interpreting TypeB as a TypeA if you are comparing elements in a list containing random elements of types A or B, you don't really care what comes in, since they can all be treated for equality. Like many other debates this one has defenders and haters.

But that's the end of the story for OOP.

In functional (declarative) languages (Lisp, F#) since the first class citizens are functions (vs Objects) polymorphism is expressed through relationships between functions and is manifested a bit differently. See [Type Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_polymorphism)

The last word I want to put out there is that I love Wikipedia as much as the rest, but you must always take articles with a grain of salt and never trust them blindly without confirming other sources. If you want to get the truth about the true principles of OOP, you should start here:

[Object-Oriented Software Construction (Bertrand Meyer)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136291554)

Answer (score 1):

I believe one of the best definitions I've seen about polymorphism refers to an object's type being discerned at Runtime. This seems to emphasize that the objects Runtime type may differ from it's declared type and that the methods invoked on the object will be matched during the Runtime process.

Comment: Ok thanks. Would this imply that a dynamic language like Ruby where there is only "runtime" that polymorphism doesn't apply? Would it all be considered Duck typing?

Comment: @Question In this discussion about polymorphism in Ruby I seem to be getting a very similar idea to way polymorphism works in say Java. It's almost like a design pattern and less related to the specific language (kinda).
Check out this discussion about polymorphism in Ruby:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137661/how-do-you-do-polymorphism-in-ruby

Comment: Thanks for the link Bnjmn, I did read this post. It seems to confirm that polymorphism can be achieved in "the exact same way, [as in C#] with classes and overridden methods". This would make the Wikipedia definition wrong, is that correct?

Comment: @Question I'm not so sure I would dismiss the Wiki entry as wrong. It mentions that "polymorphism in the context of object-oriented programming, is the ability of one type, A, to appear as and be used like another type, B." which is consistent with what we've discussed so far, and it also says "In weakly typed languages types are implicitly polymorphic." which doesn't pose a problem yet either. What part of the definition makes you so uncomfortable?

Comment: Got that, thanks. In ruby there are no static types, so it is "impicitly polymorphic".  I'm just still wondering if polymorphism in Ruby would include overriding/overloading methods in its definition? Sorry to labour the point here but the Wikipedia entry seems to claim outright that they are not polymorphic, but to my mind they are definitely polymorphic. They involve changing a method call from one object to another?

Comment: @Question I would vote to say that overriding/overloading are still polymorphic as the principle seems to matter most here. After all polymorphism doesn't refer to Ruby or Java but a general OO methodology.

Answer (score 1):

I will leave the exact definitions to someone who knows better (from a complete purist point of view), but from a purely semantic point of view, those statements do not necessarily contradict each other.

One is listing 'four different forms' of something, and the other says that two of those four forms do not "by themselves" comprise the thing. One could argue that the 'four forms' writer isn't necessarily saying that each of those forms is, itself, a "complete" example of the whole, but that they are components of.

---

That said, I think that the 'four forms' writer is more correct, and the wikipedia writer is perhaps just trying to parse something a bit much. As are you. :p

Comment: Ok makes sense, what would the other requirements be to make overriding/overloading polymorphic? Would inheritance have to be involved?

Comment: Inheritance is sort of assumed in the entire discussion, isn't it? Just like having classes is assumed.

Comment: @Andrew - yes I suppose so but as someone mentioned below 'overloading' does not have to be implemented with inheritance or a class. Would you know what are the other requirements you mentioned which would make it "completely" polymorphic? Thanks for your help

Comment: You are looking at it backwards. Correct: overloading doesn't need to exist for inheritance or classes. But overloading also has no meaning whatsoever without inheritance or classes. If you aren't inheriting anything, there is no 'overloading' at all. If you don't have classes, there's nothing *to* overload.

Comment: So, like I said: Inheritance and Classes are *assumed* in the very discussion of overloading, overriding and polymorphism. The latter three are meaningless without the first two. Think of it even further: Is 'Programming' required for polymorphism, overloading and overriding? Of course it is! (but those aren't required for programming)

Comment: You're still not answering my question, you are just arguing about how I phrased it.

Comment: I've answered your question multiple times, very succinctly in fact. If something is 'assumed', does it not clearly follow that it is 'involved'? But the problem is your question reveals a lack of understanding of the relationships of the terms, and I'm trying to help you understand them. And apparently failing badly, so I'll stop.

Comment: @Andrew - I appologise for being rude there, basically I will try to rephrase my question to you. You stated that "[wikipedia] says that two of those four forms do not "by themselves" comprise the thing [polymorphism]". I would like to know what you meant by this, if overloading/overriding methods not comprise the "whole thing", what are the other factors which need to be in play before these methods can be considered polymorphic? I appreciate you input

Comment: I would just look at all the different things that both of those authors mentioned; take those which are commonly listed, and consider those a starting point. As I suggested at the start of my answer, I can't help with a 100% "correct" answer as far as purists will be concerned, but I think the 'Four Forms' author comes closer out of what you've quoted.